# Algebraic structure of $(\text{Apply}, \{f: [T \to T]\})$? (is that even correct?)

Tags: algebra

###### Context

In a program I am writing, the user is allowed to define user-defined functions in a file. These functions have the particularity that must be of type `[T -> T]` for a given type `T`, i.e. they are endofunctions over `T`. These functions are **always** applied over the type `T` so I defined an identity function which is the default for when the user defines no custom function to apply.

###### Question(s)

Now, I was wondering about the "algebraic structure" of this, in particular the tuple `(Apply, [T -> T])`. In such a tuple, the neutral element would be the identity function. Does this type of structure have a name?

Is it even correct, given my use case, to consider `Apply` to be the operation over the set $\{f: [T \to T]\}$? Should it be considered a unary operation, or a binary operation over items from set $\{f: [T \to T]\}$ and set $\{T\}$? If the latter is the case, then what kind of structure is this?

###### Edits

- A monoid over $T \to T$ with function composition as the operation would indeed have $\text{id}$ as the neutral element, but I think this is not the case, because:

  1. Composition is not explicitly allowed. The user could define N functions and then have another that internally just composes them, but in the end she would have to choose that function over the rest.
  2. The user must choose one function from the file, and that function will always be applied to $T$ during the running of the program. Hence why I thought of $(\text{Apply}, \{f: T\to T\})$ or $(\text{Apply}, \{f: T\to T\}, T)$.
- The *tuple* $(\text{Apply}, \{f: T\to T\}, T)$ is closed over $T$, i.e. $\text{Apply}\ f\ x \in T  \quad \forall x\in T$

Comment: I'm not quite sure I have the right picture, but it sounds like you're just looking at a **monoid (acting on a set $T$)** - elements of the monoid are functions $T\rightarrow T$, the monoid operation is composition, and the neutral element of the monoid is the identity function. (Note that I'm assuming here that your collection of functions is *closed under composition* - of course if it's not, then it's a "partial monoid.")

Comment: Not sure if I understood you, but here I go: I thought at first of monoids, but a monoid over $T$ requires a binary op, i.e. $f: T\times T \to T$. During my googling I found a small excerpt about "unoids" but I couldn't get much info about them...